# jQuery getJSON: Danish letters

Tags: jquery

Im using jQuery getJSON method to get data from my database via some php code.

Im sending arrays of data from serverside to clientside via the getJSON method.

If a word in this array contains a danish letter (ÆØÅ) getJSON just returns null. I have tried to check the words before i use the getJSON and here there is no problem.

Is there an options in getJSON where i can set charset?

Im using charset ISO-8859-1 on serverside and clientside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `json_encode(utf8_encode($Content));` solves your problem, no?